Does the bent card pack have higher chances in Pokémon TCGP?
In Pokémon TCGP, when you open a pack, a circle of that pack will float down, and you can choose to open whichever one you want. However, if you turn them around, you may notice that one card pack will have a bent corner or top.

There have been some rumours online that this card pack has slightly higher chances than the others. Is this true?

why the downvotes? this is a very valid question and i was in fact wondering the same thing

TL;DR: No, it's just cosmetic.
According to the wiki (and backed up by some other sites/YouTubers that have run probability tests that I’m not mentioning),

Games that have a randomized chance of obtaining certain items must legally display the odds. In Pokémon TCG Pocket, you can check the full rates for each booster pack by clicking on the "Offering Rates" button on the bottom left corner in the booster pack screen. There would be serious legal repercussions if these rates are manipulated in such a way.


Furthermore, the cards you open are determined as soon as you press the Open a Pack button, and the game gives an illusion of choice that gives players feel like they are in control of their luck. If you close the game before making the booster pack pick and open the game again, you can see what cards are automatically added to your collection.

So there’s no difference. The fact I got a gold(!) Charizard EX (one of the three rarest cards in the game) at level 4 when opening a pack with a bent top was purely coincidence.

Really, it's just a couple of different models of card packs to give off realism in the game. The bent part is one of the many features that makes the game (and packs) look real. Pretty clever if you ask me.

People have observed that Wonder Picks show the contents of packs as soon as "Open a Pack" is pressed, which proves that the choice of pack in the carousel is irrelevant. For example, here's a YouTube short that demonstrates this.
